# How to bind "pusher:subscribe" event , using Laravel's Echo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, pusher, laravel-echo

In my laravel application i am using laravel ECHO. In this I'm trying to listen a event *"pusher:subscribe"* through **on** method. But I its not happening. I can able to subscribe, add_memeber, remove_memeber as per laravel echo documentation. But i cannot able to listen specifically  *"pusher:subscribe"* event. Actually I am trying to get data from this event and i will manipulate further

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
                broadcaster: 'pusher',
                key: 'myKeyHere',
                authEndpoint: 'pusher/auth',
                auth: {
                    headers: {

                    },
                    params: {
                        username: this.username
                    }
                }
            });


 window.Echo.join('openChat').here((users) => {
                console.log(users);

            }).listen('MessagePublished', (e) => {
                console.log('Message Received');

            }).on('pusher:subscribe', (users) => {
                console.log('NOT WORKING');

            }).joining((user) => {
                console.log('User Joined');
            }).leaving((user) => {
                console.log('User gone');
            });
```

Comment: have you registered the event listener?

Comment: @RahulDahake yes. I Registered Other events are working charm. but only `pusher:subscribe` not happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a deep lookup in documents and forums i understood `pusher:subscribe` is a internal event , so it cannot be captured through `Laravel ECHO`. But I used `pusher:subscription_succeeded` to capture the member info ..

Modified Code:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'pusher',
            key: 'myKeyHere',
            authEndpoint: 'pusher/auth',
            auth: {
                headers: {

                },
                params: {
                    username: this.username
                }
            }
        });


  window.Echo.join('openChat').here((users) => {
            console.log(users);

        }).listen('MessagePublished', (e) => {
            console.log('Message Received');

        }).on('pusher:subscription_succeeded', (member) => {
            console.log(member);

        }).joining((user) => {
            console.log('User Joined');
        }).leaving((user) => {
            console.log('User gone');
        });
```

Comment: This worked for me but how did you know to use .on() in here? There's nothing in the documentation about this as far as I can see.